# Django model for voting system

Tags: python, database-design, django-models

I am writing website to rating books and I am not sure how to implement voting system for logged users. User should be able to rate book from 1-10 and of course, system should remember his vote, count all votes and compute average rate.

Lets say I have following model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    author = models.ForeignField(Author)
    #... other fields
```

and

```
class User(models.Model):
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   #... other fields
```

Now I can add rate and rates_count fields to Book, but I need to remember users votes. Obviously I need ManyToMany field in Book class, I think something like that should be fine:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
   user_who_voted = models.ForeignField(User)
   rated_book = models.ForeignField(Book)
   rate_date = models.DateField()
   rate = models.ForeignField(User)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    author = models.ForeignField(Author)
    votes = models.ManyToManyField(through='Vote')
    #... other fields
```

I wonder if I need rate and rates_count in Book class. because I can compute their values from Vote model. There are here few unknowns for me:

How fast/slow database engine, let's say, PostgreSQL, would counting average rate for selected Book, (adding  and counting all votes vote [average rate = all votes added/number of votes]) for 10000 votes, and how for 1000000 votes. Is operation time grow constant? If I have PC 1000x times slower than server, is time need for computing will be linear too?

Sorry if my question is silly, but I'm not experienced in database programming. Thank you for any answers.

Comment: How about a `votes_on_books` table with fields `id` (django gives you this one), `book_id` as a foreign key to books, `voter_id` as a foreign key to users, and `rating`? Then when you render a book's page you can try to fetch records where book_id = current book and user_id = current id; a hit means they've already voted and you shouldn't render this page with the voting interface. You can also easily query for all votes for the current book or all votes for current user without any other cruft on the tables.

Comment: Thanks @lamChuckB. I guess it's best option. My approach is same without `votes = models.ManyToManyField(through='Vote')`, but I think django use this information for generating admin page (I'm not sure about this), so I will stay with my model.

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert in ORM's and in Django, but most SQL databases have totals that can be calculated quite fast. If you have numeric field for a rating, math would be quite easy and quick and done in one max two DB SQL calls (you will need to count number of records too). Check if django ORM has totals (i believe it does), otherwise (as I am sure that django orm also offers direct SQL) you may need to craft a custom SQL query for calculating the rate. Such query would filter required book id.

Scaling up the algorithms are not trivial. I think you maybe shall split this question, one about model and another about performance once you have some model (and maybe alternative models)

Comment: Thank you. I'm satisfied with 'quite fast' answer. I asked about scalability because I was just curious, it's not matter of life and death for me.

Comment: "quite fast" is outcome of two paths, you can approach a problem with getting the set of records (with rates) for individual book (that would be many records) and then calculate rating in a loop (or using ORMS function that would do the same for you). ORMs would incline towards such method, while when you use SQL total you'd get one result with the total and processing would be done on SQL server side (typically much faster than other methods)